# Visual Studio-DevExpress Click-Once dll's dependancy error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress, clickonce

I have developed the Windows application.
I have used devexpress tool in that app.

I have used click once to publish the application to publish it.

while publishing first time, it I have added almost all devexpress dll's while publishing it.

Now, I am publishing next version and I have removed some dll's which are not req. and I am trying to publish it.

But It gives below error.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v12.2, Version=12.2.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a'

The error is because of earlier I have published with all dlls and now I am publishing with fewer dlls by removing/excluding unnecessary dll files from application Files.

So it showing dependency error.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your application you are using the `XtraTreeList` control or controls which depends on it. If so the `DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v12.2.dll` assembly should be deployed.
You can check the lists of the assemblies required for deployment **based on the product(s)** you're using.
For example, if you are using reports? please check the [Assemblies Deployed with Windows Forms Reporting Applications](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument3189) article.

There is an easy way to collect the DevExpress assemblies required for distribution of application - [A tool for collecting the required DevExpress assemblies for further application deployment](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18730)

To add required assemblies based on products you're using, in DevExpress Assembly Deployment Tool choose the `By Products` tag page and check the corresponding (`XtraTreeList`) item.

Comment: I don't think I am looking for it... problem comes after new publish... because in earlier publish more assemblies were added and in latest publish fewer assemblies added so it showing dependency error.

Comment: @NileshB I've updated my answer a little bit... Please review it.